# Credential Provider Not Authorised Exception AWS Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I was trying to Publish and Subscribe using authenticated user on AWS IoT with Federated Identities. Until I keep getting error `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Failure to get credentials`

I looked up [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-amazon-cognito-credentials-provider/). But the snippet they provided is not used by Facebook anymore. How can I fix this issue?

Android Code:

```
    public void IntializeAwsIot() {
    clientId = "us-east-1:fcbd66e0-***************";

    // Initialize the AWS Cognito credentials provider
    credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), // context
            AWSConfiguration.AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,// Identity Pool ID
            AWSConfiguration.AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION // Region
    );

    Region region = Region.getRegion(AWSConfiguration.AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION);
    // MQTT Client
    mqttManager = new AWSIotMqttManager(clientId, CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT);


    // The following block uses IAM user credentials for authentication with AWS IoT.
    //awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("ACCESS_KEY_CHANGE_ME", "SECRET_KEY_CHANGE_ME");
    //btnConnect.setEnabled(true);

    // The following block uses a Cognito credentials provider for authentication with AWS IoT.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            awsCredentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
            Connect();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Error:

```
/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Failure to get credentials

com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity 'us-east-1:fcbd66e0-**************' is forbidden. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 0fa5100d-88a0-11e7-af8c-854a7b8add4d)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:729)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:558)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:388)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:691)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:617)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:388)
                                                                                           at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:442)
                                                                                           at com.mysampleapp.AWSIoT.PubSub$1.run(PubSub.java:69)
                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was no credential in the Cognito Cache. So we need to save the appropriate credential so the get credential function can work.

We need to just add the following.

```
    Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
    logins.put("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```